# Equation for Elevation & Azimuth after Rotation in Two Axes

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, spherical-geometry

Ideally I'd like a general equation but I've drawn a specific example of rotating a board $45^\circ$ from horizontal then $45^\circ$ on its own axis.  I haven't been able to come up with an equation to describe the resulting angle of the vector normal to the board's surface from horizontal (i.e. the angle of elevation).  I also need an equation to describe the resulting angle projected onto the horizontal plane, such as the red axis being $0^\circ$ and green being $90^\circ$ (i.e. angle of azimuth).

[image: Vector normal to surface after rotation around y-axis and around its own axis]

Comment: The initial rotation up from the $xy$-plane: is it about the $x$- or $y$-axis? Do you care? If the red and green axes are as you've described with the azimuthal angles, then you have a left-handed coordinate system, which is non-standard.

Comment: Sammy, for the goal of determining the angle of elevation, it doesn't matter whether the initial rotation is about the x- or y-axis.  It is rotated to an angle (such as 45) above horizontal, then rotated 45 degrees on its own axis.  Anyone coming up with an equation for this can define the axes as they see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the attached picture as a reference, and using the $+x$ axis to be the red solid ray pointing from from the origin to the right of the image (and down), and the $+y$ axis to be the green solid ray pointing from the origin to the right of the image (and up).  And finally the $+z$ axis to be the blue solid ray pointing from the origin, upwards to the top of the image.  This is a right handed system.

Now assume the axis of rotation as shown in the image is the line passing through the origin and making an angle of $-\phi$ with the $+x$ axis, then the **unit** vector along this axis of rotation is

$ a = ( \cos \phi , - \sin \phi , 0) $

And we want to rotate the unit vector $k = [0, 0, 1]^T $ about this axis, by an angle $\theta = +\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

According to the [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)  The rotated vector $k'$ is given by

$ k' = k \cos \theta + (1 - \cos \theta) a (a^T k) + (a \times k) \sin \theta $

Therefore, noting that $a^T k = 0$ , this simplifies to

$ k' = [0, 0, 1]^T \cos 45^\circ + [\cos \phi, -\sin \phi, 0]^T \times [0, 0, 1]^T \sin 45^\circ $

Now, $ [\cos \phi, -\sin \phi, 0]^T \times [0, 0, 1]^T = [- \sin \phi , - \cos \phi , 0 ]^T  $

Hence,

$ k' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} [ - \sin \phi , - \cos \phi , 1 ] $

Now, let $ b = [ \sin \phi , \cos \phi , 0 ] $ be the vector representing the axis of rotation for the second rotation.  However this coordinates of $b$ are before the first rotation.  After the first rotation, they become (again noting that $b^T a = 0 $)

$ b' = b \cos \theta + (a \times b) \sin \theta $

And this evaluates to

$ b' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} [ \sin \phi, \cos \phi, 1]^T $

Now we want to rotate $k'$ about $b'$ by angle of $\theta = +45^\circ$.  Using the same formula, we get the final image $k''$ as

$ k'' = k' \cos \theta + b' (b' \cdot k') (1 - \cos \theta) + (b' \times k') \sin \theta $

Noting that $b' \cdot k' = 0 $, this becomes

$ k'' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( k' +  b' \times k' ) $

We have, $b' \times k' = [ \cos \phi, - \sin \phi, 0 ] $

So that

$ k'' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} [ - \sin \phi , - \cos \phi , 1 ]  + [ \cos \phi, - \sin \phi, 0 ] \bigg)$

And in final form,

$ k'' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  [ \cos \phi - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \phi , - \sin \phi - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 }} \cos \phi , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ] $

The angle of elevation from the $xy$ plane of the vector $k''$ is just the complement of the angle it makes with $+z$ axis.  Using dot product, this is

$ \cos \psi = \dfrac{1}{2} $

Therefore, $\psi = 60^\circ$

And the angle of elevation is the complement of that, which is $30^\circ$.

Projecting $k''$ on the $xy$ plane, and normalizing, gives the vector

$ P =  \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}  [ \cos \phi - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \phi , - \sin \phi - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 }} \cos \phi , 0 ] $

If $ \tan \alpha = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $, then

$ \cos \alpha = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$

Thus,

$ P = \cos \alpha [ \cos \phi - \tan \alpha \sin \phi, - \sin \phi - \tan \alpha \cos \phi, 0 ] $

And this is equal to

$ P = [ \cos( \phi + \alpha ) , - \sin( \phi + \alpha) ,0 ] $

Hence, projected doubly rotated normal vector to the plane makes an angle of

$ \psi = - ( \phi + \alpha) $

with the positive $x$ axis.  Note that $\alpha = \tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \approx 35.26^\circ $

Comment: Hi Hosam, thank you very much.  It's interesting to see another approach.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions. Let's solve this problem in a standard [right-handed coordinate system](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Right-hand_rule#Coordinates). The $x$ axis will be the green axis pointing to the right in the image, the $y$ axis points into the visual plane along the red axis, and the $z$-axis will point upwards along the blue axis. (If we want to swap $x$ and $y$ later, the azimuthal angles will be swapped with their complements.)

It's much simpler to describe first rotating by $+45^\circ$ about the $x$-axis (counterclockwise looking down on the $yz$-plane). This is accomplished via the linear transformation:
$$
R_x = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos 45^\circ & -\sin 45^\circ \\
0 & \sin 45^\circ & \cos 45^\circ
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then we rotate by $-45^\circ$ about the $y$-axis (clockwise looking down on the $xz$-plane). This is accomplished via the linear transformation:
$$
R_y = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos 45^\circ & 0 & -\sin 45^\circ \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin 45^\circ & 0 & \cos 45^\circ
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt2 & 0 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1/\sqrt2 & 0 & 1/\sqrt2
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where we've used the negative angle identities $\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$ and $\sin(-\theta) = - \sin\theta$.

Now, the combined transformation is
$$
R_yR_x 
= \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt2 & 0 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1/\sqrt2 & 0 & 1/\sqrt2
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt2 & -1/2 & -1/2 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
1/\sqrt2 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The original normal vector is the unit normal in the $+z$ direction, namely
$$
\mathbf{n} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
and after the orthogonal transformation $R_yR_x$ it is
$$
R_yR_x\mathbf{n} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt2 & -1/2 & -1/2 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
1/\sqrt2 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\ -1/\sqrt2 \\ 1/2
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Before we find angles, we need to first project this rotated normal vector onto the $xy$-plane:
$$
\mathbf{v} = \pi_{yz}R_yR_x\mathbf{n} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\ -1/\sqrt2 \\ 1/2
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\ -1/\sqrt2 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

It will be easier if we normalize this vector:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{v}} = \frac{\mathbf{v}}{\lvert\mathbf{v}\rvert} 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt3} \begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\ -1/\sqrt2 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{2\sqrt3}{3} \begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\ -\sqrt2/2 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
-\sqrt3/3 \\ -\sqrt6/3 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, the altitude $\alpha$ (angle with respect to the horizontal) satisfies
$$
\cos \alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\ -1/\sqrt2 \\ 1/2
\end{pmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sqrt3/3 \\ -\sqrt6/3 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
= \frac{\sqrt3}{2} 
\quad\implies\quad 
\alpha = 30^\circ.
$$

The azimuth $\gamma$ (angle with respect to the positive $x$-axis) satisfies
$$
\cos\gamma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sqrt3/3 \\ -\sqrt6/3 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
= -\frac{\sqrt3}{3}.
$$

Since we can see that the $y$-component of $\mathbf{v}$ is negative,
$$
\gamma = -\arccos\Bigl(-\tfrac{\sqrt3}{3}\Bigr) 
\approx -125.264^\circ.
$$

In your original coordinates, this azimuth is
$$
90^\circ - \gamma \approx 215.264^\circ, 
$$
which is $35.264^\circ$ West of South if the red axis is North and the green axis is East.

Comment: Wow, nicely done and well explained.  Thanks, Sammy!